# Initializing a child class with the magic method __init__ of the parent class in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, magic-methods

I've been doing an online course using python.  It seems to have gone from a,b,c to z in one lesson.

In the latest lesson, in the init section of the child class it appears to take the parent class array and pass it to new magic method init parameters of the child class.

```
class ChildClass(ParentClass):
    def __init__(self, speed, direction):
        ParentClass.__init__(self, [speed, direction])
```

I couldn't find any resources on the web to confirm my interpretation.

Is the parent passing its parameters even though nothing has been assigned to self.speed and self.direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `__init__` method of the child class `ChildClass` is passing its parameters to the `__init__` method of its parent class `ParentClass`, and the parent `__init__` method then continues the object initialization.  Assuming that `ChildClass.__init__` contains only the code shown, the only point of the child method is to make the child constructor's signature different from the parent constructor's; if `ChildClass.__init__` were deleted, all calls to `ChildClass(speed, direction)` would just need to be changed to `ChildClass([speed, direction])` to continue doing the same thing.

Comment: Thanks great answer.  Could you add an example so that it is a bit clearer?

Answer (score 1):

the parent class is like creating a car class with 4 wheels.

```
car:
    def__init__(self, wheels):
        self.wheels = 4
```

you can define the number of wheels in the **init** function or below in self, however in the init you anything that is wheels = x needs to be at the end.

```
def__init__(self, wheels = 4, color):   # this would fail
def__init__(self, color, wheels = 4): # this would work
```

now we create a chevy (cause fords suck)

```
chevy(car):
    def__init__(self, wheels, color = blue):
        self.color = color

    super().__init__(wheels)
```

super comes from the parent class, anything that is in the parent class needs to be in the child class, (it wouldn't be a car anymore if it didn't have wheels) which would make it crash.